# How to give app is in development information?

Tags: android

How to give such note like the image below?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can release your app in beta mode, this banner will automatically appear which is maintained by Google.

Comment: Is it possible to deactivate the released app and release new version in beta so that user can download the beta version of app?

Comment: yes off course you can, deactivate released version and change the app version in build.gradle file and then generate signed apk and create new rollout in beta.

Comment: you can publish new beta version but prod version will still be there. if you want the only beta you must unpublish the previous app and upload the new app in beta mode.